# How to capture all instances of substring within string - using regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how to capture **ALL instances** of particular substring within a string. My substring may have 3 variations:

- AA-123BB
- AA 123BB
- AA123BB

The regex I constructed so far is capturing only one instance. I tried many combinations but still no success.
Here is my regex: https://regex101.com/r/cXqmcn/2

My PHP code is here:

```
$x = "klajshf lkjsh allashflkjh BL-345HS sjhg qkjg qwkjh g
qwdewqdwqedwqd BL345HS wqedwqehdljhwqed ZA 456KL
sdcscd";
preg_match('/([A-Z]{2}-?\s?[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{2})+/', $x, $matches);
var_export($matches);
```

And the result is:

```
array (
  0 => 'BL-345HS',
  1 => 'BL-345HS',
)
```

I guess something is wrong while the regex101 site is saying this:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

**ANSWER:**
**Aaaah sorry, preg_match_all is all I need in my PHP.**

Comment: What php code are you using?

Comment: [Your regex matches all the three strings you posted](https://regex101.com/r/jzNfdj/1)